# where to download jetty source code?

Tags: eclipse, jetty

I have download jetty 7.3 and use it in eclipse with jetty-wtp plugin.
where can I download jetty's source packages and attach them with jetty jars ?

I have found it myself at [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/search/?r=repo1.maven.org$maven2&start=0&query=org.eclipse.jetty&entity=project)

Comment: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Importing+Jetty+Source+into+Eclipse

Comment: How do you know I did not googled for "jetty"? I am looking for the downloadable jetty 7.30 source code, plz notice 7.30 not older version

Comment: A small note for future passers-by: since Jetty has moved from Codehaus to Eclipse, the most recent repository information can now be found on [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Contributor/Building).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The sources can be downloaded here:

1. [Eclipse distribution](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/)
2. [Codehaus distribution (jetty <=6, hightide, contrib)](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/)

Answer (score 14):

The best place appears to be from the Eclipse git source control repository:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/

For example I downloaded version 8.1.8 from here:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tag/?id=jetty-8.1.8.v20121106

Comment: where's the URL to clone?

Comment: @ErikAllik URL to clone is listed at the bottom of the first page: git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git

Answer (score 5):

I could not figure out how to `git clone` from `git.eclipse.org` so I found this Github mirror:

```
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project
```

so just run:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:eclipse/jetty.project.git jetty
```